# Why does ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent is not working correctly

Tags: android, image, android-intent, camera, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make broadcast reciver for new image capture.

```
            specifyIntentFilterForBroadCastRecivers = new IntentFilter(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startService(specifyIntentFilterForBroadCastRecivers,CameraImageCaptureBroadCastReciver.class);
            break;
```

my startService method:

```
private void startService(IntentFilter specifyIntentFilterForBroadCastRecivers, Class broadCastReciverClass){
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BroadCastServices.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("IntentFilter", specifyIntentFilterForBroadCastRecivers);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("Class", broadCastReciverClass);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

service onStartCommand:

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = (IntentFilter) extras.get("IntentFilter");
    Class broadCastReciverClass = (Class) extras.get("Class");
    Object broadCastReciver = null;
    try {
        broadCastReciver = broadCastReciverClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    registerReceiver((BroadcastReceiver) broadCastReciver, intentFilter);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

and broadcast onreceive

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Image Captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But it seems like MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE is not correct. I have also other intentfilters like intent.battery_low/battery_ok and it works.
Service is working correctly. 
And the question is Am I using correct intent?

Comment: why did you use service for it?

Comment: `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is used to start activities. It is not sent as a broadcast `Intent`. Your `BroadcastReceiver` will never be called.

Comment: @masoudvali I used service because my app is going to react on predefined events(I want to keep broadcast recivers alive even if user switch to other app) . Like... When battery is low, turn off wifi or somethink like that.